# ActiveAdmin sort by attribute sum of associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have the following models in my Ruby on Rails application in which I'm using Postgres Database:

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sale
end
```

There are now 2 things I want to achieve:

First, I'd like to create an index page in ActiveAdmin for Sales, so I could, for each sale, display the sum of line items prices.

What I already tried, which doesn't work very well(it's very slow):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Sale do
  actions :index
  remove_filter :line_items

  index do
    column :created_at
    column :price do |sale|
      sale.line_items.sum(:price)
    end
  end
end
```

Second, I'd like to make this column sortable - would it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for your case above you can just group based sale_id and then sum the price and to the sort with method below, reverse will get you descending order

```
LineItem.group(:sale_id).sum(:price).sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse
```

if you need probably **top ten you can use first(10)**

```
LineItem.group(:sale_id).sum(:price).sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse.first(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [registering a database view](https://lorefnon.me/2014/07/13/presenting-sql-views-through-active-admin.html) that sums the prices.  The [documentation on custom sorting](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html) should still apply.  Links to tips and tricks like this can be found on the [wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki#index-pages-filters-and-scopes).